# VBA Dumping And Pasting Values For Monte Carlo In Excel

Tags: vba, excel, simulation, montecarlo

I am trying to copy and paste loads of simulated data using vba for Excel. I have done all the calculations, it's just this final part that is failing me as I'm not very good at writing loops! What I need to do is repeatedly copy, paste and refresh a sheet onto a range- then move onto the next unused row and continue the process. Once this is done I will then use vlookups and index+matches to obtain the data I need from these arrays. Here is the code that I have (without the loops):

```
Sub Sim()
Worksheets("Sim Results").Range("N2:R21").Copy
Worksheets("Sim Table").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Sim Results").Range("N2:R21").Copy
Worksheets("Sim Table").Range("A22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Sim Results").Range("N2:R21").Copy
Worksheets("Sim Table").Range("A42").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Sim Results").Range("N2:R21").Copy
Worksheets("Sim Table").Range("642").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

The loop goes in sets of 20, for instance the target cells would be A2, A22, A42, A62, A82... etc. It will also require a "do until" loop that allows me to repeat this process thousands of times...

Can somebody help me please? Otherwise I'll just have to copy these lines a few thousand times!

Edit: Here's the solution:

```
Sub Sim()



i = 0

Do Until i = 1000

Worksheets("Sim Results").Range("N2:S21").Copy



Worksheets("Sim Table").Range("A" & 20 * i + 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually there is no need to use loop for copy/paste. You can just write it in one row: `Worksheets("Sim Results").Range("N2:R21").Copy:  Worksheets("Sim Table").Range("A2,A22,A42,A62,A82").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` . You can use loop to create string of destination addresses: `"A2,A22,A42,A62,A82"`. Try it and if you get stuck with it - I'll help you:)

Comment: Hi simoco, the main problem is that I want to simulate thousands of permutations, so the destination address doesn't stop at A82. Ideally the last cell will depend on the amount of simulations input in the first place, hence my idea of a "do until" loop...

Comment: That's true, but I sad that you don't need loop for copy/paste, but need loop to generate destination address: `"A2,A22,A42,A62,A82,..."` (or alternatively you can calculate destination range `A2:E82` - instead `82` - real number corresponding to your needs). It's really easy. Try do to it yourself, and if you would get some problems with it - show us what have you tried and what doesn't work and we would be glad to help you:)

Comment: Cheers simoco, I've managed to solve it!